# Blog wordpress-moveble type

Tags: wordpress

I am about to launch a recipe blog. I like to be able to interact with comment, have a star rating system, sell ad and have a custom section for client (mini site)

have you any experience on movable type over wordpress ?, which is the best "out of the box" solution ... maybe enhanced with some plug in from the community

thanks in advance

--

as said in comment : moved to [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/53025/blog-wordpress-moveble-type)

Comment: Has no more to do with ServerFault than StackOverflow. It's not a sysadmin question. SuperUser, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check out the plugins for each platform and see what is available, as some of those functions are not core to either platform. [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), [MovableType](http://plugins.movabletype.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a lot of plugins and is well known. Check out the plugins here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Other than using these systems, you could go down the paid route.